# How to select Product and Variant in separate fields in Sales order?

Tags: product, odoo, variant

In Odoo 8's `product.py` I see the `name_search` method concatenates the product name and variant as the product name. I however have hundreds of attributes to my product.

Height: 500mm, 505mm,... 3000mm

Width: 500mm, 505mm,... 4000mm

So it makes it impossible to search the desired variant

So I need first select the **product**, then the **Height** attribute, then the **Width** attribute

In theory I need to override the search method

1. Remove the variant in product name
2. Create a search method to select first attribute
3. Create another search method to select second attribute
4. Then it needs to return the product name + att1 + att2 to main search method

```
class product_product(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'product.product'
#This search filter the products by selected product category   
    def search(self, cr, uid, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, context=None, count=False):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        if context.get('material_id'):
            productobj = self.pool.get('product.product').read(cr, uid, context['material_id'],['materialoptions_id'])

            args = [('categ_id','=',productobj['materialoptions_id'][0])] + args
        return super(product_product, self).search(cr, uid, args,  offset, limit, order, context=context, count=count)

#And this is where I want to sperate the product and its attributes 


#DONT KNOW WHERE TO EVEN START WITHOUT BREAKING THE PRODUCT.PY NAME_SEARCH
```

`product.py`

```
def name_get(self, cr, user, ids, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        if isinstance(ids, (int, long)):
            ids = [ids]
        if not len(ids):
            return []

        def _name_get(d):
            name = d.get('name','')
            code = context.get('display_default_code', True) and d.get('default_code',False) or False
            if code:
                name = '[%s] %s' % (code,name)
            return (d['id'], name)

        partner_id = context.get('partner_id', False)
        if partner_id:
            partner_ids = [partner_id, self.pool['res.partner'].browse(cr, user, partner_id, context=context).commercial_partner_id.id]
        else:
            partner_ids = []

        # all user don't have access to seller and partner
        # check access and use superuser
        self.check_access_rights(cr, user, "read")
        self.check_access_rule(cr, user, ids, "read", context=context)

        result = []
        for product in self.browse(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, ids, context=context):
            variant = ", ".join([v.name for v in product.attribute_value_ids])
            name = variant and "%s (%s)" % (product.name, variant) or product.name
            sellers = []
            if partner_ids:
                sellers = filter(lambda x: x.name.id in partner_ids, product.seller_ids)
            if sellers:
                for s in sellers:
                    seller_variant = s.product_name and (
                        variant and "%s (%s)" % (s.product_name, variant) or s.product_name
                        ) or False
                    mydict = {
                              'id': product.id,
                              'name': seller_variant or name,
                              'default_code': s.product_code or product.default_code,
                              }
                    result.append(_name_get(mydict))
            else:
                mydict = {
                          'id': product.id,
                          'name': name,
                          'default_code': product.default_code,
                          }
                result.append(_name_get(mydict))
        return result
```

Comment: I have considered creating my own attribute fields... rather than battling with this search method. but the existing attribute functionality is just what i need. In the sense that its linked to it own Bill of materials. Please Please Please help me :) willing to send cash for code haha

Answer (score 0):

So what I think the best "Work Around" would be is if I create 3 custom fields

- Product Type (All the product names in selected category)
- Width (attributes linked to product selected in 'Product Type')
- Height (attributes linked to product selected in 'Product Type')

above the product field. Then by concatenating those 3 values I can pass the context 'name' to the product search method to match. Therefore only displaying one product matching the criteria above

Hope this helps -me-

Why is this the best way? probably shouldve added this. educational value and what not.

Because, whilst debugging you'll see the product and it's attribute shares an id. That is because odoo treats each product variant as a product. There's no "main" product and then it's child variants. It's one in the same.

```
LOOK HERE===================================================

{'lang': 'en_US', 'tz': False, 'uid': 1, 'material_id': 19}

LOOK HERE3===================================================

{'lang': 'en_US', 'tz': False, 'uid': 1, 'material_id': 19}

[33, 34, 35, 36]

LOOK HERE2===================================================

{'default_code': False, 'id': 33, 'name': u'Palisade Fence (Domestic 110mm) (1800, 3000mm)'}

LOOK HERE3===================================================

{'lang': 'en_US', 'tz': False, 'uid': 1, 'material_id': 19}

[33, 34, 35, 36]

LOOK HERE2===================================================

{'default_code': False, 'id': 34, 'name': u'Palisade Fence (Domestic 110mm) (1800, 3005mm)'}

LOOK HERE3===================================================

{'lang': 'en_US', 'tz': False, 'uid': 1, 'material_id': 19}

[33, 34, 35, 36]

LOOK HERE2===================================================

{'default_code': False, 'id': 35, 'name': u'Palisade Fence (Domestic 110mm) (1805, 3000mm)'}

LOOK HERE3===================================================

{'lang': 'en_US', 'tz': False, 'uid': 1, 'material_id': 19}

[33, 34, 35, 36]
```

Which is why each variant has it's own Bill of materials (Which is exactly what i need, Thank you brilliant odoo developers) So unless you want to change the structure of odoo, you first need to pass a context to filter the products, not the other way around

Hope this makes sense everyone. I'm VERY new to programming so please tell me if I'm missing the plot.

odoo is INCREDIBLE thanks guys